# Does standard configuration in Tomcat pose any security risk?

Tags: webserver

I have a simple test website on Tomcat running on RaspberryPi. Pi is behind a router. Port forwarding is on and I can access the website from the Internet.

What are the security risks of standard out of the box configuration? Only user and password to Tomcat changed or actually added.

Can someone access my RaspberryPi because of that Tomcat?

Wasn't sure if that question should go to Server Fault or here.
On Server Fault, there is a similar question, but unanswered 6 months old.

Comment: Your Tomcat will only be as safe as the web applications you deploy on it.

Comment: Restrict/remove manager apps, change default passwords, store pw in hashes, read the CIS guide.